# Two generic methods with the same name

Tags: c#, generics

Is not possible (except use different name) to have several generic methods with the same name but implementing different interface ?

```
public IList<T> List<T>() where T : class, IMyInterface1
{

    return mylist
}

public IList<T> List<T>() where T : class, IMyInterface2
{

    return mylist
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't overload just by generic type constaints. You can overload by the *number* of type parameters, but not on their constraints.

If you're *implementing* an interface you can use explicit interface implementation - otherwise I'd suggest just using different names. I often find that using different names makes things clearer anyway, to be honest.

Bear in mind that the example you've given introduces natural ambiguity anyway - what would you expect to be called if the type argument implemented *both* interfaces?

Comment: I would expect a compiler error. For instance, something I was contemplating right now was having two identically-named generic methods, one which would return `T` and have a `where T: class` constraint, and the other which would return `Nullable<T>` and have a `where T: struct` constraint. So someone could pass in a `T` of `int` or `int?` and invoke the correct method. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way but being able to specialize this generic using what should be a mutually exclusive constraint would be useful.